# Selected options in CheckBox list not being pased to ActionResult when submitted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have both a `CheckBox` list and a `Radio` list in a form but when the form is submitted the selected options for either list are not passed to the ActionResult. What am I missing?

`if (Model.IsMultipleChocie)
{
    foreach (var Choice in Model.Choices)
    {
        <li>
            @Html.CheckBox("Answers", Choice.Value)
            @Html.Label(Choice.Key)
        </li>
    }
}
else
{
    foreach (var Choice in Model.Choices)
    {
        <li>
            @Html.RadioButton("Answers", Choice.Value)
            @Html.Label(Choice.Key)
        </li>
    }
}`

`public ActionResult ProcessVote(int[] Answers, int UserID, string UserIP, int ID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.CheckBox("Answers", Choice.Value)` does not set the `value` attribute so you would need to use `@Html.CheckBox("Answers", new { value = Choice.Value })`. However as noted in the comment below, `@Html.Checkbox()` renders a second hidden input with `value="false" so you posting back an array which includes`int`and bool` values so binding will fail.

Either create the checkboxes manually

```
<input type="checkbox" name="answer" value=@Choice.Value />
```

or create a view model to represent what you want to display. For example

```
public class AnswerVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public class MyVM
{
  public bool IsMultipleChoice { get; set; }
  public List<AnswerVM> Answers { get; set; }
  public int? SelectedAnswer { get; set ; } // for single choice
}
```

View

```
@model MyVM
....
if (Model.IsMultipleChoice)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < Model.Answers.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Answers[i].ID)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Answers[i].IsSelected)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Answers[i].IsSelected, Model.Answers[i].Name) // associate label with the checkbox
  }
}
else
{
  foreach(var answer in Model.Answers)
  {
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedAnswer, @answer.ID)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Answers[i].Name)
  }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourMethod(MyVM model)
{
  if(model.SelectedAnswer.HasValue)
  {
    // property SelectedAnswer contains the ID of the selected answer (from radio button)
  }
  else
  {
    foreach(AnswerVM answer in model.Answers)
    {
      if (answer.IsSelected)
      {
        // answer.ID contains the ID of the checked answers (from checkboxes)
```

Note: `RadioButtonFor()` renders duplicate `id` attributes so you can give each a unique ID (say based in `answer.ID`) so you can use an associated `<label for ..>`

Comment: I changed that and see that the HTML mark up has `value ="VALUE"` now but `int[] Answers` is still `null`. I checked the markup and the checkbox's `ID` and `NAME` are set to Answers.

Comment: OK, the problem is that `@Html.Checkbox` renders 2 inputs, the second one will have a value of `"false"`. When the values are posted back you get an array of (say) `["1", "false", "2", "false", "3", "false" ....]` and because `"false"` is not an `int` the binding will fail. I suggest you use a view model or (not recommended), manually create the inputs.

Comment: What would a VM for this look like? I would still need to the INT values as that is what is saved in the DB. Why would it not be recommended to create old school checkboxes?

Comment: No real problem using _old school checkboxes_, it just that I've seen so many questions on SO where binding fails because `name` attributes don't match model properties - stupid typo's or not understanding collection indexers. I always prefer to use the view models and strongly types helpers.

Comment: I ended up having to create them using HTML